# A glitched NPC is refusing to move

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

For the last 8 minutes, I've been trying to get an NPC to move. It's Delpine at the inn and she won't move . I haven't started the main quest yet and she wont die! Any advice on how to get her to move?

Comment: Is this on PC? because if so then get the Skyrim patch, it fixes almost every glitch.

Comment: Ok is this a mod from nexus?

Comment: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19/? There's the link for you. There's also patches for all the DLC's as well!

Comment: Ok no problem, want me to make it a answer so this question can be closed?

Comment: Yes if you dont mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Here**](http://nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/19?) is a link to the USP (Unofficial Skyrim Patch) It fixes almost all bugs, glitches anything for the main game and all the DLC's too.

I have had no problems with this mod and it has helped massively as Skyrim is a glitchy game on its own.